# How to add fragment to fragment transaction?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I want to open a fragment from an activity, I followed a youtube video that explained it this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
FragmentForJoyScreen fbeer = new FragmentForJoyScreen();
ft.add(XXX, fbeer);
ft.commit();
```

Whereas in the video XXX = R.id.fragment_container which I can't find in my android studio. When I type R.id.f it doesn't complete me and when I write R.id.fragment_container it shows it has an error. For an hour I searched the internet for an answer and couldn't find something that helped me.

What should be instead of XXX? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better or different way to load fragment from an activity?

Comment: the id of your main layout, or layout of your FragmentActivity or AppcompayActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what the layout in your Activity is. So look at the layout that's inflated in setcontentview(R.id.yourlayout). Your XXX is the name of the framelayout that your fragment will replace inside R.id.yourlayout, or possibly R.id.yourlayout itself if that is a framelayout.

Also, you should write your fragments to use the newinstance pattern, so you can use FragmentForJoyScreen.newinstance() instead of new FragmentForJoySCreeen.

Comment: Thanks I used the newinstance pattern

Answer (score 0):

R.id.fragment_container or XXX should be a View in xml file where you gonna replace it with selected Fragment object

It can be Fragment or FrameLayout

Please look at this [link](http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu)

Comment: FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        FragmentForJoyScreen fbeer = FragmentForJoyScreen.newInstance();
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentForThreeIcons, fbeer);
        ft.commit();

Comment: It still says there is an error on ft.add(R.id.fragmentForThreeIcons, fbeer);
But in the XML file I did add the id to the fragment layout, the fragment layout IS named fragmentForThreeIcons.